# Why does $\lim_{n \to\infty}a_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Assume that $\{a_n\}$ is a convergent sequence. How to use the definition of a limit of a sequence to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}a_{n+1} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$?

Comment: $a_{n+1}$ is a subsequence of $a_n$.

Comment: cauchy criteria $\lim_{n \to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n) =0$, from here you could conclude the above thing.

Answer (score 6):

Write $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$. This means that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a whole number $N$ such that for all integers $n\ge N$, $$|L-a_n|<\varepsilon$$ Now, to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=L$ as well, consider any $n\ge N$ and note that $n+1\ge N$. So by our initial statement, $|L-a_{n+1}|<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a matter of notation.

For $n \ge 1$,
considering $a_{n+1}$ means the sequence $a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, \dots$, and
considering $a_n$ means the sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, \dots$.

Limits are a matter of the eventual behaviour of the sequence, and it is not surprising that the limit (if it exists) is the same for "both" — it's the *same* sequence whose eventual behaviour you're considering.

Put differently, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{m-1\to\infty} a_m = \lim_{m\to\infty} a_m = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$$
as $m-1\to\infty$ and $m\to\infty$ are the same thing.

Comment: I have no idea why someone downvoted this; this still seems correct to me. It's useful to step away from notation and formal definitions for a bit and think about what one is saying.